# Brownie compile dependencies into contract

Tags: python, solidity, brownie

I have a solidity project referencing openzeppelin contracts. To compile that I am using `python` with `eth-brownie`.

When I compile the project with `brownie compile` it works perfectly with one caveat. All the dependencies goes into dependencies folder.

What I want is to generate only one contract file with including all imported libraries in header part.

My `brownie-config.yaml` file looks like this

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0'
```

I had searched alot over the internet but cannot find anything related to

**compiling dependencies with brownie**

**brownie flat file**

nothing comes up except at some where I read brownie doesn't support that. There must be a way to do that

**Can any one help me to generate contract in one single file including all dependencies on top?**

Thanks